# $state.go() not working with angular and onsenui

Tags: angularjs, cordova

This is my app.js

```
  var Myapp = ons.bootstrap('Myapp',[]);
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    }, false)
```

controller.js :

```
Myapp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'LoginSrvs', function          ($scope, $state, LoginSrvs) 
 {
          $scope.login = function (LoginAccount) {
          debugger;
          var username = LoginAccount.username;
          var password = LoginAccount.password;
          var parameter = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password       });
        var loginData = LoginSrvs.login(parameter);
         loginData.then(function (str) {
    })
    $state.go('index');
};
```

}]);

and my  route .js

MyApp.config(
                    ['$stateProvider',
                     '$urlRouterProvider',

```
        function ($stateProvider,
                  $urlRouterProvider) {
            debugger;

            $stateProvider

                .state('index', {
                    url: '/index',
                    templateUrl: ''
                })

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        }]);
```

`state.go` not found and not trigger the  controller action on click.

Comment: may be it is because of your templateUrl you should show the index.html file path in there

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want any content then replace `templateUrl: ''` with `template: ''`.

Comment: when i click on login button it never hit the $scope.login in Login controller

Comment: make sure you are passing 'LoginAccount' from login button.

Comment: <div class="login-form">
                <input type="text" style="width:100%;padding-top: 24px;padding-bottom: 24px;" ng-model="LoginAccount.username" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Username" value="">
                <input type="password" ng-model="LoginAccount.password" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" value="">
                <br><br />
                <input type="button" ng-click="login(LoginAccount)" value="LogIn" style="height:38px;" class="login-button button " /> 
                <br><br>
            </div>

Comment: Myapp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'LoginSrvs', function          ($scope, $state, LoginSrvs)

Comment: $state remove from that controller then it hit to login .